# What is the fastest, reliable baud rate that can be used using radio modems?

Tags: c, serial-port, communication, modem, radio-transmission

I need to communicate with 30+ devices, via serial data over radio modems (Using C). Each cycle of messages should be done as quick as possible. (< 500ms)

Basic setup would be a master sending out a broadcast, then each slave replying within their allotted time slot with their status, all synchronised nicely.

We'll be using a frequency of around 870Mhz (license free), but I'm wondering what the physical limitation is, and what this would equate to in terms of maximum reliable (95%+) baud rates?

Does anyone have any experience in this field that knows a ball park figure?

Comment: Depends on bandwidth and signal-to-noise ratio - if you don't know these then you can't specify a maximum data rate. Also this is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Complicating factors not mentioned: The kind of antenna, the distance and terrain, other interfering sources, the transmitter power, … . You might want to get someone with radio experience if all you know is the software protocol and the frequency band.

Comment: @PaulR: I'd make that the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Shannon-Hartley theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ0gK.png) to determine an upper bound on the data rate. You will need to know the *bandwidth* and the *signal-to-noise ratio*. Plug these numbers into the formula and you will then have an upper bound on data rate:

[image]

```
C == channel capacity (bits per second)
B == bandwidth of the channel (Hz)
S/N == signal-to-noise ratio (NB: linear power ratio, not dB)
```